# ProcessBuilder delete and rename

Tags: java, macos, command, processbuilder

I am having a `ProcessBuilder` that should delete `File.txt` and then rename `NewFile.txt`.
Problem is that both files are deleted. Any idea why and how to fix?

```
public class MyProcessBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();

        // CREATE FILES
        File file = new File("File.txt");
        File newFile = new File("NewFile.txt");     
        try{
            if(!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            if(!newFile.exists())
                newFile.createNewFile();
        } catch(Exception e){}

        // force remove File.txt
        command.add("rm"); 
        command.add("-f");
        command.add("File.txt");

        // rename NewFile.txt to File.txt
        command.add("mv");
        command.add("NewFile.txt");
        command.add("File.txt");

        final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        try {
            builder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are running a single command, namely

```
rm -f File.txt mv NewFile.txt File.txt
```

This unconditionally deletes files named `File.txt`, `mv` and `NewFile.txt`.

You want to split this into two separate commands.

Better still, use [`File.delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) and [`File.renameTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29). This will not only give you more control, but will also make your code more portable.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that answered my question.. What I really would like to do is to: Run Program.jar, Delete Program.jar, Rename NewProgram.jar to Program.jar, Run Program.jar. Because I am running the Program.jar(File.txt) it can´t be deleted. Might be solved with one ProcessBuilder fo each command?

Answer (score 0):

ProcessBuilder.start creates one process. You need to call it twice because you have two commands: first with the first command and then with the second.

Incidentally, why are you not using Java's file API for this? It is a lot easier to do this from Java than to deal with the complexity of launching a separate process, not to mention more efficient.